# Counting Just One Record Per Pupil Though Multiple Are Matched

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I've set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ec85/2) to illustrate the question...

I have a database of pupils (referenced by PupilId) who have assessments (AssessmentLevelId) recorded in various subjects (NCSubjectId) at various period (PeriodId).

Not every possible period may have an assessment in it.

```
PupilId | PeriodId | NCSubjectId | AssessmentLevelId
-----------------------------------------------------
100     | 1        | 10          | 1
100     | 3        | 10          | 2
200     | 1        | 10          | 1
300     | 1        | 10          | 1
400     | 1        | 10          | 1
100     | 5        | 10          | 2
300     | 7        | 10          | 2
100     | 15       | 10          | 2
```

I want to find the number of pupils who have a particular assessment level by a particular PeriodId.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT PupilId, COUNT(1) FROM NCAssessment
WHERE AssessmentLevelId = 2
    AND NCSubjectId=10
    AND PeriodId <= 10
GROUP BY PupilId
```

Which finds the pupil ids, but pupil 100 has a count of 2. I guess I need to wrap this in another query but am stumped. Any suggestions?

This is using Azure SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this might be what you are looking for:

`AssessmentLevelId = 2` has been removed from the query, because some Periods may not have an assessment.

```
SELECT AssessmentLevelID, PeriodID, COUNT(DISTINCT PupilID) 
FROM NCAssessment 
WHERE NCSubjectId=10 AND 
      PeriodId <= 10 
GROUP BY AssessmentLevelID, PeriodID
```

If this isn't correct, could you please post a sample result you are expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of distinct pupils that match, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PupilId) as NumMatchingPupils, COUNT(*) as NumMatchingAssessments
FROM NCAssessment
WHERE AssessmentLevelId = 2 AND NCSubjectId = 10 AND PeriodId <= 10;
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` will count each pupil once, regardless of the number of maps.  `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` will count the number of assessments that match.